# Image in form causing issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Here is my issue - I am trying to make a locked page on my website for committee members... And when I have the image as an input for the form it adds something odd to the navigation bar of my browser...(Example: ?x=632&y=43) Which prevents me from linking to the right page correctly

Here is my Code for the locked page link-

```
<div class="logon">
  <SCRIPT>
    function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter The Password','');
    while (testV < 3) {
       if (!pass1)
           history.go(0);
       if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "qwertyuiop") {
           alert('You Got it Right!');
           window.open('target.html');
           break;
       }
       testV+=1;
       var pass1 =
       prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
   }
   if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3)
       history.go(0);
   return " ";
}
</SCRIPT>
<FORM>
<input type="image" class="logonimg" src="/img/Committee Member Access.png" onClick="passWord()">
</FORM>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS for that page

```
.logon {  
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ff9999;
    border: 5px solid #ff9999;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.logonimg { 
    height: auto;
    width: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those are `GET` variables they are creating `state` on the page. Why would you want to "fix" them? Do you mean you would like neater URLs? There are a number of solutions for that, have a look at url routing.

Comment: What do you mean "linking to the right page?"

Comment: try removing the `form` tags